# Uncrustify: initialization list: starts with comma

Tags: c++, initialization-list, uncrustify

I would like to archive a following code structure automatically by Uncrustify:

```
  Class(int aArg1, int aArg2, int aArg3)
      : BaseClass(aArg1)
      , iMember1(aArg1)
      , iMember2(aArg2)
  {
  }
```

I've tried Uncrustify version: 0.63:

```
pos_constr_comma = lead_force
```

but it doesn't work. What should I set to have a code like above?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. Try adding this:

```
nl_constr_init_args=add
```

Did the trick for me.